# Inner classes not apearing in jar

Tags: java, jar

I execute the following command:

```
jar cfm build/IMUI_Widget_Agent.jar "/Users/doekewartena/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/95e850bb40bbc92a4f5e7bd720c0b61e/redhat.java/jdt_ws/imui_1a91146f/bin/imui/core/IMUI_Widget_Agent_MANIFEST.MF" -C "/Users/doekewartena/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/95e850bb40bbc92a4f5e7bd720c0b61e/redhat.java/jdt_ws/imui_1a91146f/bin" "imui/core//IMUI_Widget_Agent$Begin_Element.class" -C "/Users/doekewartena/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/95e850bb40bbc92a4f5e7bd720c0b61e/redhat.java/jdt_ws/imui_1a91146f/bin" "imui/core//IMUI_Widget_Agent$End_Element.class" -C "/Users/doekewartena/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/95e850bb40bbc92a4f5e7bd720c0b61e/redhat.java/jdt_ws/imui_1a91146f/bin" "imui/core//IMUI_Widget_Agent$Using_Widgets.class" -C "/Users/doekewartena/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/95e850bb40bbc92a4f5e7bd720c0b61e/redhat.java/jdt_ws/imui_1a91146f/bin" "imui/core//IMUI_Widget_Agent$Widget.class" -C "/Users/doekewartena/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/95e850bb40bbc92a4f5e7bd720c0b61e/redhat.java/jdt_ws/imui_1a91146f/bin" "imui/core//IMUI_Widget_Agent$Widget_Transformer_CFT$1.class" -C "/Users/doekewartena/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/95e850bb40bbc92a4f5e7bd720c0b61e/redhat.java/jdt_ws/imui_1a91146f/bin" "imui/core//IMUI_Widget_Agent$Widget_Transformer_CFT.class" -C "/Users/doekewartena/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/95e850bb40bbc92a4f5e7bd720c0b61e/redhat.java/jdt_ws/imui_1a91146f/bin" "imui/core//IMUI_Widget_Agent.class"
```

Here I changed the path to make it a bit more readable:

```
jar cfm build/IMUI_Widget_Agent.jar "/java/bin/imui/core/IMUI_Widget_Agent_MANIFEST.MF" -C "/java/bin" "imui/core//IMUI_Widget_Agent$Begin_Element.class" -C "/java/bin" "imui/core//IMUI_Widget_Agent$End_Element.class" -C "/java/bin" "imui/core//IMUI_Widget_Agent$Using_Widgets.class" -C "/java/bin" "imui/core//IMUI_Widget_Agent$Widget.class" -C "/java/bin" "imui/core//IMUI_Widget_Agent$Widget_Transformer_CFT$1.class" -C "/java/bin" "imui/core//IMUI_Widget_Agent$Widget_Transformer_CFT.class" -C "/java/bin" "imui/core//IMUI_Widget_Agent.class"
```

But in the jar, only the `IMUI_Widget_Agent.class` is there, all the classes with a `$` in the name like `IMUI_Widget_Agent$Begin_Element` are missing.
How does such a thing happen?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on some UNIX or UNIX-like shell (e.g., bash), $INNER in OUTER$INNER.class is being interpreted as an environment variable reference and expanding to nothing.

```sh
$  echo jar cfm build/IMUI_Widget_Agent.jar "/java/bin/imui/core/IMUI_Widget_Agent_MANIFEST.MF" -C "/java/bin" "imui/core//IMUI_Widget_Agent$Begin_Element.class" -C "/java/bin" "imui/core//IMUI_Widget_Agent$End_Element.class" -C "/java/bin" "imui/core//IMUI_Widget_Agent$Using_Widgets.class" -C "/java/bin" "imui/core//IMUI_Widget_Agent$Widget.class" -C "/java/bin" "imui/core//IMUI_Widget_Agent$Widget_Transformer_CFT$1.class" -C "/java/bin" "imui/core//IMUI_Widget_Agent$Widget_Transformer_CFT.class" -C "/java/bin" "imui/core//IMUI_Widget_Agent.class"
jar cfm build/IMUI_Widget_Agent.jar /java/bin/imui/core/IMUI_Widget_Agent_MANIFEST.MF -C /java/bin imui/core//IMUI_Widget_Agent.class -C /java/bin imui/core//IMUI_Widget_Agent.class -C /java/bin imui/core//IMUI_Widget_Agent.class -C /java/bin imui/core//IMUI_Widget_Agent.class -C /java/bin imui/core//IMUI_Widget_Agent.class -C /java/bin imui/core//IMUI_Widget_Agent.class -C /java/bin imui/core//IMUI_Widget_Agent.class
```

Try using single quotes (') instead of double quotes (").